# Find an analytic function

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Is it possible to find an analytic expression for a smooth, continuous, single-variable function $y=f(x)$ such that:

1) $f(0) = 0$

2) $f(x_1) = y_1$

3) $f(x) > 0, \forall x>0$

4) $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x) = c_1$

5) $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f'(x) = c_2$

If it is possible, can you give an example? I am especially interested in solutions parametrized by the constants $x_1$, $y_1$, $c_1$ and $c_2$.

I have tried with weighted average of two linear functions using the inverse tangent function, namely:

$y = p_1(x)(1-w(x))+p_2(x)w(x)$,

where

$p_1(x) = c_1 x$,

$p_2(x) = c_2 x - c_2 x_1 + y_1$,

$w(x) = 0.5(1+2\cdot\mathrm{atan}(w_1(x-w_2))/\pi)$.

But this does not give proper results or I was unable to find the appropriate constants $w_1$ and $w_2$ from the parameters given.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you have 3 conditions, I think a linear combination of three "basic" functions would do. E.g., $\operatorname{arctan}$ to get the limit at infinity and $e^{-x}$, $e^{-2x}$ to take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take

$$f(x)={(x-x_1)^2\over (x+x_1)^2}[c_1\arctan(x)+c_2{x^2\over 1+x}]+{y_1\over x_1^2 e^{-x_1}}x^2e^{-x}$$

The difficulty is condition (3), that $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, but the initial term makes this possible.

Obviously one assumes $x_1,y_1,c_1,c_2>0$ for the problem to be sensible.

Another solution, as discussed in comments is:

$$f(x)=\biggl(1-{x^2\over (1+x^4)}{1+x_1^4\over x_1^2}\biggr)^2\biggl[c_1\arctan(x)+c_2x\cdot(1-(1-x)^2e^{-x})\biggr]+{y_1\over x_1^2 e^{-x_1}}x^2e^{-x}$$

Comment: What was the reasoning behind this solution?

Comment: How is $x_1>0$ necessary?

Comment: As the original comment said, you want to use $\arctan(x)$ and $e^{-x}$. To match the derivative at infinity, I used ${x^2\over 1+x}$ as it asymptotes to $x$ but has zero derivative at zero. Then to finally make $f(x_1)=y_1$, I killed off the first term with the $(x-x_1)^2$, and just added what was wanted, with a function that had zero derivative at both endpoints (and was nonnegative). At least in my solution, $x_1>0$ is necessary for I use $(x+x_1)^2$ in the denominator. But the front multiplier needs: $M(x_1)=0$, $M(0)=M(\infty)=1$, $M(x)\ge 0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: I guess you can the multiplier be $M(x)=(1+{Cx^2\over 1+x^4})^2$ for appropriate $C$ to make $M(x_1)=0$, that is, $C=-{1+x_1^4\over x_1^2}$. When $x_1=0$ you have $y_1=0$ and the condition is already made. But my solution still does not make sense at $x=-1$ for instance.

Comment: A way to fix that is to replace ${x^2\over 1+x}$ by $x[1+(1-x)^2e^{-x}]$. The point is that this (dividing by $x$) is 1 at infinity and 0 at zero, keeping everything aright.

Comment: Note that $(1-(1-x)^2e^{-x})$ is positive (else I would square it I guess).